# AWS S3 find files by name

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm really suprised that there is no easy way to scan all of files in S3 via `aws-sdk` node package and find some file by his name or some regex.

Here is an example of folder structure:

```
- mainDirectory

    - directoryOne
        (...)
        - file1.png
        - file2.png
        (...)

    - directoryTwo
        (...)
        - file11.png
        - file22.png
        ( ...)

    - directoryThree
        (...)
        - file111.png
        - file222.png
        (...)
```

Is there any option to use `Delimiter` or `Prefix` in that way to list files from EVERY directory named `file(...)`?

Tried this:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET,
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'file'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the prefix in [list api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) is used to match object keys starting from the beginning, not relative to part of the key.

If you have a huge amount of objects and timing doesn't matter for you, then I recommend setting up S3 inventory to generate a daily inventory report. Then you can process it using Athena with some SQL queries.

If you need to scan it and get the objects in real time, I would recommend also saving the object key to other data structure for fast query.